# How to select greater Id using LINQ To SQL

Tags: asp.net, linq, list, c#-4.0

I have code to get list of id from database. The code is done using LINQ that is below

```
var resutls = (from v in con.NewsLatter
               where v.SendStatus == "Active"
               select new { v.Id }).ToList;
```

It return a all id from database which from table called NewsLater. Now what I'm trying to do is fill this all id in

```
List<Int32>  IdList = new List<Int32>{ //list of id want to fill here in  List<Int32> };

var min = IdList .Where(x=>x>12).Min();

return min;
```

When I try to fill this like this below

```
List<Int32> IdList = new List<Int32> { Convert.ToInt32(resutls) };

var min = IdList .Where(x => x > 12).Min();

return min;
```

I got an exception:

```
 Unable to cast object of type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.Int32]]' to type 
'System.IConvertible'.
```

Anyone have a any idea what was wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [AddRange method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx):

```
List<Int32> IdList = new List<Int32>()

IdList.AddRange(resutls)
```

Assuming that `resutls` is a `List<Int32>` itself though, which is look like it is from your code.

EDIT:

Change your query to:

```
var resutls = (from v in con.NewsLatter
               where v.SendStatus == "Active"
               select v.Id).ToList();
```

You just need to select `v.Id`, you don't need to create a new object `new { v.Id }`.

Comment: Got 2 bugs its below:
Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.AddRange(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>)' has some invalid arguments
and
Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'

Comment: it will throw Error 1 Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable

Comment: I change my code, as I was missing brackets next to `ToList()`. Try my code again please. It will work, I just tried it in a console app on my PC just now.

Comment: yes thanks you so much Jason for help me to solve this issue =)

Comment: i have one other question if in IdList table there was no more Rows more then 50 or 400 how can we return 0 value at that case with this query?

Comment: i got my answer :) use .DefaultIfEmpty() for that

Answer (score 0):

Try it , first declare converted value in a int variable and then give the value .

**Edited**

```
         foreach (var result in resutls)
        {
            int convertedResult = Convert.ToInt32(result);

            List<Int32> IdList = new List<Int32> { convertedResult };
            IdList.Add(convertedResult);
        }
```

Comment: Hello Ramesh it will throw same bug.